# Meteor Error: EACCES: permission denied, rmdir 'build'

Tags: node.js, meteor, npm

I have this error when i try to update my meteor project from Meteor 1.3.5.1 to METEOR 1.4. I don't know why i have this error. I have already try to do a chown to .meteor and .np floder.

```
 => Errors while initializing project:         

    While loading package npm-bcrypt@0.8.7:
    error: Command failed:
    /home/noob/.meteor/packages/meteor-tool/.1.4.0.hylsrj++os.linux.x86_64+web.browser+web.cordova/mt-os.linux.x86_64/dev_bundle/bin/npm
    rebuild --no-bin-links --update-binary
    gyp ERR! clean error 
    gyp ERR! stack Error: EACCES: permission denied, rmdir 'build'
    gyp ERR! stack     at Error (native)
    gyp ERR! System Linux 3.16.0-38-generic
    gyp ERR! command
    "/home/noob/.meteor/packages/meteor-tool/.1.4.0.hylsrj++os.linux.x86_64+web.browser+web.cordova/mt-os.linux.x86_64/dev_bundle/bin/node"
    "/home/noob/.meteor/packages/meteor-tool/.1.4.0.hylsrj++os.linux.x86_64+web.browser+web.cordova/mt-os.linux.x86_64/dev_bundle/lib/node_modules/npm/node_modules/node-gyp/bin/node-gyp.js"
    "rebuild"
    gyp ERR! cwd
    /home/noob/.meteor/packages/npm-bcrypt/.0.8.7.1np1i1l++os.linux.x86_64+web.browser+web.cordova/npm/node_modules/.temp-140iag7/node_modules/bcrypt
    gyp ERR! node -v v4.4.7
    gyp ERR! node-gyp -v v3.4.0
    gyp ERR! not ok 

    npm ERR! Linux 3.16.0-38-generic
    npm ERR! argv
    "/home/noob/.meteor/packages/meteor-tool/.1.4.0.hylsrj++os.linux.x86_64+web.browser+web.cordova/mt-os.linux.x86_64/dev_bundle/bin/node"
    "/home/noob/.meteor/packages/meteor-tool/.1.4.0.hylsrj++os.linux.x86_64+web.browser+web.cordova/mt-os.linux.x86_64/dev_bundle/bin/npm"
    "rebuild" "--no-bin-links" "--update-binary"
    npm ERR! node v4.4.7
    npm ERR! npm  v3.10.5
    npm ERR! code ELIFECYCLE
    npm ERR! bcrypt@0.8.7 install: `node-gyp rebuild`
    npm ERR! Exit status 1
    npm ERR! 
    .....
```

Comment: Haha!  Love the username `noob`! Anyway, it's failing to remove a directory `build`, which I am guessing is under the `.meteor` folder for your project somewhere.  Lots of reasons this could happen, like for instance on Windows and some OSes it can't remove a folder you are physically in.  It looks like you are on *nix, so that's probably not the case.  But I have seen several people posting about bcrypt issues on Linux today, so I am guessing there is some bug/issue effecting Meteor 1.4 builds. you could try nuking everything in .meteor/packages and see if it fixes.

Comment: ahha yes i agree, noob is a good username :p

Answer (score 16, accepted):

It was an permission error
I do a `sudo chown -R $USERNAME /home/noob` and now all work fine

Comment: Awesome.  I figured it was an issue w/ the filesystem.

Answer (score 1):

Look more like a Node-gyp problem.

Extracted from [Meteor docs](https://guide.meteor.com/1.4-migration.html#binary-packages-require-build-toolchain):

> If you have binary npm packages in your application node_modules
>   directory, you should run meteor npm rebuild (after meteor update) in
>   your application directory to recompile those packages.

If it still doesn't work, try removing your `~/.node-gyp` file and then `npm update`.

Answer (score 0):

Had to delete bcrypt directory

rm -r $HOME/.meteor/packages/npm-bcrypt/.0.7.8_2.f294j7++os.osx.x86_64+web.browser+web.cordova/npm/node_modules/bcrypt